# Rule-based styling road crossing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, style

Styling/symbolizing (rule-based option) a roads vector layer with intersections of streets with different styles I have incorrect (and annoying) overlaps of the different symbolization styles. is it possible fix the problem?

[image]

I also add the symbolization level window
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the symbol level of the feature you want on top to a value higher than the other ones. This is true both vertically (road type) and horizontally (component of the road style for a given road type).

In your example, if you want the blue line on top, set the last line, layer1, to a value of 3.

It may also be necessary to hit `apply` on the main styling window to see the changes.

As an example, the following symbol levels will draw the green area (0), then the  blue area (1) and at last, on top of everything, the center line from the low line (3)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well :). If I understood correctly, then should I hierarchically organize road types and assign the same hierarchy to the color symbol levels?

Comment: @Andrew-63 yes. And you can be fancy too, like putting "lower class" center-line above "higher class" buffer

Comment: "And you can be fancy too, like putting "lower class" center-line above "higher class" buffer", sorry, I do not know if I understand, could You show me an example about, please?